# Copying to targets where the files already exist: skip or stop

Tags: macos, finder

I noticed that sometimes, when I tell Finder to copy files to a location where some of those files already exist, Finder gives me the option to "skip" those files and then proceeds to copy the rest.

But at other times, more often I guess, Finder gives me the option to "stop" (or to "replace") and there is no "skip" option.

I cannot figure out what triggers either behaviour.

Today both happened within the same hour when I was copying files from an internal disk to an external disk. The first time I could simply drag and drop all the files and tell Finder to skip the files that already existed on the external disk. The second time Finder didn't give me that option.

Any ideas what makes Finder decide to offer or not offer the useful skip option when copying files?

Comment: The answer by mwoods worked for me. If this question is really about the reasoning behind this unreasonable behavior (IMHO), then all good. If, however, the question is more about how can we enable the skip option despite it not being shown, then I think you can safely accept mwoods spot-on answer.

Comment: I was actually moving many files from internal to external disk as well, when I encountered this issue. I haven't fully tested it BTW, but my impression is that it depends on the amount of files - above some threshold it hides the skip option. If so - sounds like some kind of a technical risk that the developers were trying to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what makes Finder choose one dialog over the other, but you can make the Skip button appear by holding down Option.

Comment: I'll try that. Ta.

Comment: Just. Wow. Thank you mwoods! Why would Apple do that?? What would any PM or dev get up one morning and say "Hey! wouldn't it be cool if we hide the only way to safely merge two folders?" What dark interest would promote the dichotomy of either you copy everything or nothing?? But thank you mwoods. Really saved me a huuuuge amount of time 